# Setfacl configuration issue in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am configuring a Linux Server with ACL[Access Control Lists]. It is not allowing me to perform setfacl operation on one of the directoriy /xfiles. I am able to perform the setfacl on other directories as /tmp /op/applocal/. I am getting the error as :

```
root@asifdl01devv # setfacl -m user:eqtrd:rw-,user:feedmgr:r--,user::---,group::r--,mask:rw-,other:--- /xfiles/change1/testfile setfacl: /xfiles/change1/testfile: Operation not supported
```

I have defined my `/etc/fstab as /dev/ROOTVG/rootlv / ext3 defaults 1 1 /dev/ROOTVG/varlv /var ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/ROOTVG/optlv /opt ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/ROOTVG/crashlv /var/crash ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/ROOTVG/tmplv /tmp ext3 defaults 1 2 LABEL=/boot /boot ext3 defaults 1 2 tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0 devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0 sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0 proc /proc proc defaults 0 0 /dev/ROOTVG/swaplv swap swap defaults 0 0 /dev/APPVG/home /home ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/APPVG/archives /archives ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/APPVG/test /test ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/APPVG/oracle /opt/oracle ext3 defaults 1 2 /dev/APPVG/ifeeds /xfiles ext3 defaults 1 2`

I have a solaris server where the vfstab is defined as

cat vfstab

```
 # fd - /dev/fd fd - no - /proc - /proc proc - no - /dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/swapvol - - swap - no - swap - /tmp tmpfs - yes size=1024m /dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/rootvol /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/rootvol / ufs 1 no logging /dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/var /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/var /var ufs 1 no logging /dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/home /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/home /home ufs 2 yes logging /dev/vx/dsk/APP/test /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/test /test vxfs 3 yes - /dev/vx/dsk/APP/archives /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/archives /archives vxfs 3 yes - /dev/vx/dsk/APP/oracle /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/oracle /opt/oracle vxfs 3 yes - /dev/vx/dsk/APP/xfiles /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/xfiles /xfiles vxfs 3 yes -
```

I am not able to find out the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should care about formatting, really..

Answer (score 1):

Your fstab line is unreadable, but you may need to turn on the `acl` option for ext3 in your /ifeeds partition:

```
/dev/APPVG/ifeeds /xfiles ext3 defaults,acl 1 2
```